# Getting individual values from an ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to get the individual values from an ArrayList but I haven't had any luck.
It appears that when I go through the loop, it's overwriting the i Integer variable being used in the for loop.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getTests() 
{
    return tests;
}


// Go through all the tests downloaded from the bluetooth module
        for (Integer i :ma.mOpacityTestResult.getTests())
        {
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_report_row, (ViewGroup) container, false);
            TextView left = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowLeft);
            TextView right = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowRight);

            // This is the checkbox we want shown but to only worth with counter
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            check.setChecked(true);


            String testResultString = getString(R.string.TestNumber) + String.valueOf(counter++);

        // Load getTest Results into a list
          List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
          list.add(i);          // Trying to seperate each value of i download from bluetooth here but failing
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep initialization out of the loop

This should be outside the loop

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Only addition of values to list should be in the loop

```
list.add(i);
```

Comment: If I want to get the first element of the list by using list.get(0), it's still returning the last item of the i variable even though I've specifically selected the 0 index.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating a new list on every iteration and adding the value. So at the end of final iteration, only the list created in the last iteration will be left, which gives a feeling that the value in the list is being overwritten. To fix this, the list initialization (List list = new ArrayList<>();) has to be done outside the for loop.

Comment: I added the List initialization outside the for loop the i variable is still getting overwritten

Comment: Can you please paste the updated code? It should ideally work.

Comment: It turns out that by using a switch statement, I wasn't somehow getting the correct values from the list but when I was using if.. statements it was working.